# Using in one project code "C# via XAML" and "C++/CX via XAML"

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I want to use in one application WinRT code "C# via XAML" and "C++/CX via XAML".

The first form is written in "C# via XAML", the second form is written in "C++/CX via XAML".

Open the form the following code:

```
//C# -> C++
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageOnCPP));
```

And

```
//C++ -> C#
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
//...
this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(PageOnCSharp::typeid));
```

How can I do both of these in a single project?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio doesn't allow two different languages in the same project.  If you want to do this you will need to create a second project for your second language.  You can then reference the project and use your other class.